# How can I test arguments passed to a render prop?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I have the following component, `Layout`:

```jsx
const Layout = ({ children, data, ...otherProps }) => (
  <ErrorBoundary>
    <App render={({ isSidebarOpen, scrollTop, toggleSidebar }) => (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Helmet
          title={get(data, 'site.siteMetadata.title')}
          meta={[
            { name: 'description', content: get(data, 'site.siteMetadata.description') },
            { name: 'pinterest', content: 'nopin' },
            { name: 'og:title', content: 'Daniel Spajic' },
            { name: 'og:description', content: get(data, 'site.siteMetadata.description') },
            { name: 'og:type', content: 'website' },
            { name: 'og:url', content: get(data, 'site.siteMetadata.siteUrl') },
            { name: 'og:image', content: ogImage },
            { name: 'og:locale', content: 'en_AU' },
          ]}
        >
          <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href={favicon} />
          <link href="https://afeld.github.io/emoji-css/emoji.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </Helmet>
        <div id={PAGE_CONTENT_CONTAINER_ID}>
          <Sidebar isOpen={isSidebarOpen} toggle={toggleSidebar} />
          <div id={PAGE_CONTENT_ID}>
            {children({ scrollTop, toggleSidebar, ...otherProps })}
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )}
    />
  </ErrorBoundary>
);
```

As shown it renders an `App` with a `render` prop. The `isSidebarOpen` and `scrollTop` arguments for the prop are both from `App`'s state. `toggleSidebar` is one of `App`'s methods.

I want to test a few things:

1. The rendered `Sidebar` sets its `toggle` prop to `toggleSidebar`, and `isOpen` prop to `isSidebarOpen`
2. The `children` function is called with an object containing `scrollTop`, `toggleSidebar`, and `otherProps` as its argument

These involve retrieving `App`'s state and methods for comparison. I've tried accessing its state with Enzyme, but it's not possible because [`state()`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/state.html) can only be accessed on the root node:

```
ShallowWrapper::state() can only be called on the root
```

Therefore how can I access `App`'s state and methods so I can test these things?

Comment: `expect(shallowWrapper.find(Sidebar).props().isOpen).toBeTruthy()`? Is this what you want?

Comment: @HardikModha nope, I want to do something like `expect(sidebar.props().isOpen).toBe(isSidebarOpen)`, where `isSidebarOpen` is from `App`'s state. I could hard-code it instead of fetching the state, but that'd be brittle

Comment: @dspacejs You should hard-code it then. 'Brittle' is a good thing in unit tests. If a test fails and needs to be fixed when relevant code changes, it's ok. If a test passes when it shouldn't because it relies on another malfunctioning behaviour, it's not ok.

Comment: @estus ok thanks, but what about `toggleSidebar`? The only way to test that is by accessing the method itself. You can hard-code the others, but not in this case since it's a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShallowWrapper::state() can only be called on the root` may not be a problem because tested values should be preferably hard-coded in unit tests. It's better to make a test unintentionally fail where it should pass than to make it unintentionally pass where it should fail, the former is much easier to debug and fix.

Though it may be beneficial to get component state, at least for assertions.

```
const layoutWrapper = mount(<Layout/>);
const appWrapper = layoutWrapper.find(App).dive();

expect(appWrapper.state('isSidebarOpen')).toBe(false);
expect(appWrapper.first(Sidebar).props('isOpen').toBe(false);

appWrapper.setState({ isSidebarOpen: true });

expect(appWrapper.state('isSidebarOpen')).toBe(true);
expect(appWrapper.first(Sidebar).props('isOpen').toBe(true);
```

There's a lot of moving parts in this component, this is also suggested by that it should be tested with `mount` and not `shallow`. it may be beneficial to provide fine-grained isolated tests, i.e. test `render` prop separately:

```
const layoutWrapper = mount(<Layout/>);
const appWrapper = layoutWrapper.first(App);
const Child = appWrapper.prop('render');

const childWrapper = shallow(<Child isSidebarOpen={false} ... />);

expect(childWrapper.find(Sidebar).props('isOpen').toBe(false);
...
```

And how `App` state interacts with `render` prop should be tested in dedicated `App` component test.

Comment: Thanks, this works for solving #1, but what about #2 (testing `Layout`'s `children` prop)?

Comment: Ah, sure. For this one I guess it's `let childrenCallback = jest.fn(); mount('<Layout>{childrenCallback}</Layout>'); expect(childrenCallback).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...)`.